# RegEx to match certain string in sentence if a criteria is matched

Tags: regex

I need to match the sentence `NEED TO MATCH THIS TEXT` only if the the word `This_Criteria` is present.
For example the line below contains the word `This_Criteria` thus the result of the regular expression should be: `NEED TO MATCH THIS TEXT`.

```
<182>Nov 16 15:38:10 172.27.27.224 This_Criteria,Jun 29 03:26:33 trm92 sshd[1033]: NEED TO MATCH THIS TEXT
```

How can this be achieved no matter what the sentence contains?

So in pseudo:

If This_Criteria=true ignore everything from This_Criteria up to : and match what comes after

Hope I've explained my self correctly!

Comment: does `NEED TO MATCH THIS TEXT` may appear before the string `This_criteria`?

Comment: Hello. NEED TO MATCH THIS TEXT always comes after This_Criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
This_Criteria.*?\[1033\]: *([^:]+)$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/eM7jK8/2)

and grab captured group #1 from match.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for the answer. I tried this in RegexBuddy and it captures everything from This_Criteria to the end of the sentence. However, I want the regex to look for This_Criteria and if present in the sentence, then match any text after [1033]:

Comment: This_Criteria will always be before the NEED TO MATCH THIS TEXT

Comment: Hello,I'm using RegexBuddy. I checked the Demo which gives the correct result. In RegexBuddy the result is: This_Criteria,Jun 29 03:26:33 trm92 sshd[1033]: NEED TO MATCH THIS TEXT

Comment: You need to look at capture group #1 not the entire match, I made it very clear in my answer.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to regular expressions. Sorry I should have mentioned this earlier. What do you mean to look at capture group #1? Thanks

Comment: You need to do little bit of reading before attempting a regex solution. Read grouping and capturing her: http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html

Comment: I will thanks. Just need to see which regex languages this applies to. Thanks.

Comment: Got it working with your example with a slight modification. This_Criteria.*?\[[0-9]+\]: *([^:]+)$ Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Simple.
Just run the normal regex for this, but include `This_Criteria` in the beginning of it. If it can't find `This_Criteria`, it will not match.

**But**, if you are asking for people to do your regex for you...

Depending on how specific you want the text to be, something like this should do the trick:
`/This_Criteria.*\[[0-9]+\]:(.*)/`

This will match everything after the final `[1033]:` (any numbers), ONLY if `This_Criteria` is there.
This is very simple regex, and if you want to be more specific you're going to have to edit that.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for the answer. I have tried what you mentioned but it does not work in Regex buddy. I have tried all short of regex combinations for the last two days and nothing works! after the final [1033]: I need to match any text that follows not just numbers. Thanks

Comment: Hi again. If I try it like this This_Criteria.*\[[0-9]+\]:(.*) it then matched everything from This_Criteria to the end of the sentence.

Comment: Yeah sorry, the / at the start and end are for code. Regex Buddy doesn't require those.